# Accessing WebDav from Server Link

Tags: webdav, ithit-webdav-server, ithit-ajax-file-browser

I've downloaded the .Net Server and ajax library

We need to be able to edit documents directly from the WebDav Server.
I've succeeded doing so with the javascript code using MicrosoftOfficeEditDocument and JavaEditDocument

I'd like to be able to have in my pages a link as follows

\server\DAV\path\file

When I place a similar link like above, it doesn't open the file. When I copy link and place in windows run command, it opens

Is it possible to have direct links to webdav storage files for opening?

Also, Is there a planned solution for the jar file running in Chrome?

I've followed the instruction for https://java.com/en/download/faq/chrome.xml#npapichrome

This allows chrome to load the jar file, but They say they stop supporting.

Answer (score 0):

To open a document from a web page your link must be HTTP or HTTPS, that is start with http://server/. It would not work with a network path.

In your case URL must look like http://server/DAV/path/file.ext